# Webpack cannot resolve package of babel core

Tags: webpack

I am trying to incorporate webpack into my electron project to enable hot reloading. I started with a simp[le webpack configuration to pack dependencies in a bundle. My configuration is :

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');    

let config = {
  target:'electron',
  entry:'./app/Initializer',
  output:{
    path:path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'appbundle.js',
    publicPath:'/dist/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions:["",".js",".jsx"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders:[{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    },
      {
        test: /\.json/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = config;
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/babel-core/lib/api/node.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../package in /home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api
resolve file
  /home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/package doesn't exist
  /home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/package.js doesn't exist
  /home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/package.jsx doesn't exist
resolve directory
  /home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/package doesn't exist (directory default file)
  /home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/package/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/package]
[/home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/package.js]
[/home/shashi/projects/kaal-clients/atman-desktop/node_modules/babel-core/package.jsx]
 @ ./~/babel-core/lib/api/node.js 42:15-39
```

The babel-core does have a valid package.json file, thus I am not sure why this error is being thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding ".json" to the extensions variable under resolve fixed this

```
resolve: {
    extensions:["",".js",".jsx",".json"]
  }
```